# Homework - Cross product of 3 points in 2D space

Tags: c, math, vector

I'm mostly unfamiliar with vectors, so wondered if I might get some help here.

I'm working a convex hull project in 2d space. The specific function I'm working on needs to determine if a point lies to the left of a line, to the right, or directly on the line.

I've been told to do this using a cross-product. The three points create a triangle in 2d space. Computing the cross product is supposed to give me the area of the triangle. If the area is positive, points p-> q-> r work counter-clockwise, meaning that point r lies to the left of line p-q. Likewise, if the area is negative, points p->q->r work clockwise, and point r lies to the right of line p-q. If the area is 0, r lies on line p-q.

I understand what to do with the end result, I just have no idea what formula I'm supposed to be using.

My problem is that I'm unfamiliar with the cross-product, and the research I've done doesn't clarify how to do this with 3 points. My hunch is that it's the same process as doing it with 2 vectors, but if this is the case, I have no idea how exactly to translate my 3 points into 2 vectors.

Thanks very much!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Math and has little/nothing to do with programming. See http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Note that the cross product is defined between vectors and not points. For three points you can declare two vectors of its sides, like in the answer given by Martin R below.

Comment: @Vache My apologies, that would have been a much better place to put this.

Comment: See the [Graham scan algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) on wikipedia, where this cross product and its application to finding the convex hull is extensively discussed. No guarantee on correctness or completeness of the full algorithm there, but the basics are correctly covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your triangle has the sides `q-p` and `r-p`, so you have to calculate

```
(q - p) x (r - p)
```

where `a x b` is the *determinant*

```
a x b = (a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x)
```

which is sometimes called "2-dimensional cross product" (see for example
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html).

Comment: So if p = (1, 4); q = (2, 5); r = (3,6); it would be a = (1, 1) and b = (2,2)? Therefore, a x b = (1 * 2 - 1 * 2) = (2 - 2) = 0? Maybe my random numbers weren't so ideal if it's 0, but is that process correct?

Comment: @bumbleBumble: That is correct. Those three points are on a straight line, therefore the result is zero.

Comment: @bumbleBumble: Btw, the cross-product gives the area of the *parallelogram* that is spanned by the difference vectors, which is twice the area of the *triangle*.